# Undefined variable and functions

Tags: function, variables, gcc, compiler-errors, linker

I want to understand how does a C-compiler and linker handles when the c-source code file has a undefined variable and an undefined function call?

For example if my main function is following:

```
void main(void)
{
 myvar++;
 myfunc();
}
```

There is no definition of myvar in the source file and also there is no function with name myfunc() in the source file.

My understanding is that compiler will give error for unknown variable of myvar. And linker will give error for myfunc(). But I have not clear understanding for the inside steps (means the logical steps taken by toolchain) of the compiler and linker when they come across these lines and throw these errors.

Let us say I am using GCC compiler, linker for an ARM MCU.

Comment: What do you mean with `inside steps`?

Comment: @ssbssa now explained it in the post above. My main motive is to understand the steps that are taken by the toolchain. For example when does the toolchain do memory management steps to allocate memory to the variables and function? So does the errors occur before mem management step or after that?

Comment: Also at what step a toolchain checks the internal and external linkages of variables and function calls.. is it before memory management step or after that?

Comment: `that compiler will give error for unknown variable of myvar. And linker ...`  the compiler does not produce object/exe file in case of error, how can you have something to link ? or you reuse the result of a previous compilation to link with so the source you give does not correspond to your problem

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not execute the actual code, but looks at its correctness in terms of syntax. It must register the creation of a new variable when it encounters that in the code and yes, that means it stores the existence of that variable, but not the variable itself. So, if your code creates an array of 10 000, then the compiler does not have to allocate that amount of memory. Instead, it will store in some variable/structure under the hood that a variable with a given type is created. So, when the compiler encounters a code that refers to a variable, the compiler can check whether a variable with that name has been created/initialized in the scope it is being referred to and whether the operation performed on the variable might be syntactically correct. So, if you created an array, then dividing it with 5 will not make any sense whatsoever, hence the compiler will know that the operation is invalid. Yet, if you refer to the 10001's element in the array, while it does not exist, that's a runtime error.

So, logically, the compiler cannot check for the existence of a variable without storing the fact that the given variable exists first.